# Airflow BashOperator prints 'could not find xxx to execute'

Tags: python, subprocess, airflow

When I use BashOperator to run `pg_dump`. Airflow prints `could not find a "pg_dump"` in log. However, airflow successfully use the `pg_dump` and did the job after it's printed out.

```
[2023-12-19, 14:24:13 EST] {subprocess.py:75} INFO - Running command: ['/usr/bin/bash', '-c', 'pg_dump -Fc -v -n $SCHEMA --exclude-table measurement_orig -f $OUT_FILE ]
[2023-12-19, 14:24:13 EST] {subprocess.py:86} INFO - Output:
[2023-12-19, 14:24:13 EST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - could not find a "pg_dump" to execute
[2023-12-19, 14:24:13 EST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
[2023-12-19, 14:24:13 EST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - pg_dump: reading extensions
[2023-12-19, 14:24:13 EST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - pg_dump: identifying extension members
[2023-12-19, 14:24:13 EST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - pg_dump: reading schemas
[2023-12-19, 14:24:13 EST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
[2023-12-19, 14:24:13 EST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
...
```

I'm curious where this information comes from and why Airflow is printing out this message.

Deployment Information:

```
airflow version: v2.6.0
executor type: LocalExecutor
server: Red Hat 7.9
```

Running `which pg_dump` gives me result `/usr/bin/pg_dump`

Comment: Where exactly did you run `which pg_dump`? Are you sure it is installed Airflow worker? Does it work with absolute path `bash_command="/usr/bin/pg_dump"`?